# Need clarification on a bounty, trying to piece together what happened

Tags: support

After reading the bounty FAQ I'm still confused.   I started a question about an Android problem [Where did the arrows go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233997/where-did-the-arrows-go-android-calendarview#38241004), which didn't generate much response, so I added a 100 point bounty.

I got two answers.  In one the answerer did lots of interesting background digging, into the innards of Google's Android code, but didn't leave me much of a practical solution.    In the other the answerer used the discoveries of the first answerer, plus his own knowledge to give me a code fragment I could just paste into my own work for a solution.

I selected the one with code fragment as the answer because it solved my problem, but the other answer got more upvotes (9 vs 5).

At the time I checkedmarked the selected answer **both** answers had little blue "+100" icons.   I clicked the one under my selected answer a message popped up asking if I was sure, because it can't be undone, and when I clicked OK it said "there is no open bounty on this question".   So why did it show a +100 and ask if I was sure, when there was no open bounty?

I refreshed the page in my browser and the +100 was replaced by a +50.

So what happened?   Who got the bounty, and how much, and why is there a +50 now?   BTW, my goal is to award both answerers some of my rep points because they both contributed.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question here, but you don't really need to add things like "(Android CalendarView)" to your question title. That's what tags are for :).

Answer (score 4):

It seems you didn't choose who to award the bounty to before the bounty grace period expired, so it automatically awarded half the bounty to the answer that gathered the higher score during the bounty duration (the higher scoring answer predated your bounty, so it was not eligible for auto-awarding, see [the help center on bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) for the exact rules).

In the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38233997/revisions), you can see this happened 2 days ago.

> occurred 2 days ago
>
> Bounty Ended with Pravin Divraniya's answer chosen by Community♦

As for how you might have seen the tools to award the bounty more-recently, perhaps you still had the page open from before.

Comment: So if Pravin got the bounty why is there a +50 still there now, after the page refresh?     Also why did Pravin get it since his answer only had 5 upvotes but lulian's had 9?    Finally, if Pravin got the 100 point bounty I'd still like to give lulian some of my rep points to thank him for his work, so how do I do that?

Comment: @user316117 lulian answered before you posted the bounty. Answers posted before the bounty are not eligible for being awarded the bounty by the automatic mechanism. The assumption is that if you posted a bounty after an answer was posted, that answer did not actually *satisfy you*. You could have given lulian the bounty if you had explicitly done it before the bounty expired.

Comment: @user316117 Those questions are answered in [the help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) And you _could_ post another bounty to give lulian a bounty reward, but, as stated in the page I just linked, you'll have to post a 200 point bounty and you won't be able to just let it expire to give him half of that, since the answer was posted before the bounty started.

Comment: So, short of a bounty, is there any way on Stack Overflow to just give someone some of your rep points to thank them for their work?

Comment: @user316117 A bounty is really the only way to award an answer reputation points apart from upvoting it.

Comment: That seems like a flaw in Stack Overflow.   This isn't the first case I've seen where there were **multiple** good answers where several posters put a lot of work into them.  But you can't predict that when you set out the bounty and because the bounty system doubles the point award each time, it's not suitable for situations like that, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to [Alexander's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328263/1079354), the reason you likely saw the +100 on either side of the question was due to the UI.  If you offer a bounty, you see the amount eligible to be offered next to each answer, analogous to one seeing a faded green checkmark next to multiple answers in a question.